# Why is finding the factors of a number an algorithm with exponential time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Why does this algo have an exponential time complexity?

I understand that "Modulus" is a bitwise operator and operates on individual bits. Hence In the worst case, we need to perform sqrt(2^n) divisions. So this is an exp time algorithm.

If that is true, won't all algo become exponential time? Please explain.

```
Find-Factor(X)
1: if X is even then
2: return ”2 is a factor”
3: end if
4: for i = 3 to Sqrt(X) by +2 do 
5:    test if X%i = 0, if yes, output ”i is a factor”
6: end for
7: return ”X is a prime.”
```

Comment: i don't quite understand the line 4...

Comment: The modulo is a division, not a bitwise. It can become a bitwise only if the divisor is an exact power of 2 and literal.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr please check. I have changed the line

Answer (score 3):

Exponentiality comes from the number of iterations. In the worst case (which is the case number is prime) You have to do X / 2 iterations (in this algorithm and it is not a good one, for instance you can limit the loop with sqrt(X) instead of X). And this is exponential with the number of bits in your input = ln(X). Not with number X.

By the way, there are probabilistic checks which determines whether a given number is prime or not very quickly. And also there is a rather complicated algorithm which does the same job deterministically. You can google and find them.

Comment: The one voting down, can you enlighten me with the reason? Is there something wrong?

Comment: am more concerned with how this came about. Not particularly prime number algo. I want to know why 2^n and how come this does not apply to all the other algos.

Comment: That was me, for "you have to do X/2 loops", and for "comes from the number of for loops".

Comment: Give me an algorithm and I'll try to explain its time complexity. By the way I have to note that there is a distinction between the time complexity of a problem and an algorithm. You cannot write an algorithm with a time complexity less than the problem's complexity. But you can always do worse. Currently there is no proof for the time complexity of the problem "finding factors of a number" is exponential. (However the best algorithm for the problem is exponential). And also there is a polynomial algorithm for the same problem for quantum computers.

Comment: @jthill Before the edit the algorithm was searching till X and with increments of 2. Therefore in the worst case, there are X /2 loops. Any mistakes in my explanation?

Comment: It's linear search. You don't have to do X/2.  You led with two false assertions -- one of which (number of for loops) I now see is just English not being your native language.  (edit: to be constructive, you meant "number of iterations") Switching to conversation here, there's actually proof by example that factoring is sub-exponential but in a way that doesn't help enough to matter.

Comment: @jthill Yes, you are right English is not my native language and yes I meant number of iterations. And yes again I checked and see that there are sub-exponential algorithms for the problem in hand. For that I thank you. I've learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

They're exponential in the length of the number's representation because the representation itself is exponential, the next digit is 10<sup>n+1</sup> or 2<sup>n+1</sup> or whatever.  The linear search just has that much more to search through, that's all.

Comment: The representation is itself exponential ? What does this mean.Are you referring to the next prime number's occurrence.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. This is mentioned in the wikipedia page on Integer factorization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity

Comment: To expand, your answer makes sense if we are are considering the time complexity with respect to the length of the representation. I also understand that this is the relevant measure for large numbers. However, why is this the relevant measure when considering the general time complexity of the algorithm? In other words, why is integer factorization not considered to be in the complexity class P when Trial Division (which I think is more or less the OP's algo) has a bound of O(sqrt(N)) https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/50326/what-is-the-average-case-complexity-of-trial-division

Comment: @JohnHenderson It's specifically because of cryptography, by far the heaviest-hitting use of factorization, where increasing the length of a key is easy and the big question is "what impact does increasing the length of a key have?".It's something like string manipulation, you generally don't care what values the individual characters have, you care how many of them there are.

Comment: Thanks @jthill, make sense. For reference for others, I also found this answer on math.stackexchange which discusses this further: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1624390/why-isnt-integer-factorization-in-complexity-p-when-you-can-factorize-n-in-o%E2%88%9A
In particular one of the comments ("The complexity is always calculated by the length of the input. It's just that in most cases, the input is some sort of data structure (for example, an array) of  elements. So the length of that type of input is ") was helpful for me.